# Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()

Tags: php

hello i have this code which try to insert data in the database but i face error rong parameter count for mysqli

```
<?php

session_start();

$regValue = $_GET['regName'];

echo "Your registration is: ".$regValue.".";


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "b4sonic";
$dbname = "b4sonic2";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO b4sonic (first_name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param( $firstname);

// set parameters and execute

$firstname = "John";
$stmt->execute();


echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

please i ness rapid respone because i work on project and i should comlete it but this probelm

Comment: Place `$firstname = "John";` above your `bind_param`. *"please i ness rapid respone because i work on project and i should comlete it but this probelm"* - How's that for fast! - *You're welcome*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put `$firstname` above your line:

> ```
> // prepare and bind
> ```

```
$firstname = "John";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO b4sonic (first_name) VALUES ('$firstname')");
```

Comment: thank you for your replay its work correctly

Comment: @BisherAndoura Personally, I think you picked the wrong answer. Devon's answer covered **all** the problems. This answer does **not**. Plus, Devon's answer was the first. Another thing, there is nothing **to** prepare here.

Answer (score 4):

Fred addressed one issue.  At the time of bind_param, `$firstname` isn't defined.

You also aren't calling [**bind_param**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) correctly.

The first parameter needs to identify the variable type.  For instance `'s'` for string.  Refer to the link I added.

```
// define the variable first
$firstname = "John";

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO b4sonic (first_name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $firstname);

// set parameters and execute
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Lordie; yeah, good catch on the `s` thing. What was I thinking? lol More coffee please.

Comment: Well I don't know if I would have realize he didn't define $firstname, I usually skim lol.  So together we prevail.

Comment: There ya go, that's what it's about ;-)

Comment: Ironic how they "wanted it fast". They come by, get an answer without even saying *"hey, thanks! It works"* then a green ticky; but no. Pathetic.

Comment: Yeah, maybe we were too fast.  I'm used to not getting recognition in that case.  </sexjoke>

Comment: Oh well, what can you do. Least you got something from it ;-)